# How can I correctly style the font Arial on IE11?

Tags: css, windows-7, fonts, internet-explorer-11

On IE 11, I have font-family:Arial.  It puts a space after the letter w.  It will like this,

```
w hat's up w this Arial font?
```

If I change the browser size, hold control, scroll wheel, the font will look better.  The font size is 11px.  If I change that to say, 12px, it looks better.  On IE 10, I have no problems.

How do I get the Arial font, the way I have it styled with CSS, to look correct, without changing to a different font (all other fonts look okay, incidentally.)

```
font-family:Arial;
```

I have re-installed the Arial font on the computer.  It did not help.

The spacing is only in the viewing.  If printed, or auto-completed (the dropdown remembering feature of IE, it is spaced correctly, it looks fine.  If I use my search terms in a search on my site where the input uses Arial, and has the odd spacing, it returns the results.  It is only the visual aspect.

Thanks.

Comment: Not reproducible. I just downloaded and installed IE 11 (on Win 7) and tested with 11px Arial (which is not illegal, but should be), without observing the problem. You should post a minimal page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/96cc55cd-3f74-4061-86b7-b4ac7c309a17/extra-space-appears-after-letter-w-when-used-with-arial-font-and-font-size-8pt?forum=ieitprocurrentver  It is like this.  No, that is not me.

Comment: I have seen this issue as well. It seems to be sporadic, 'resolves' itself in a day or two and has been very difficult to nail down the cause. I know this sounds crazy, but my best guess so far is that IE 11 just doesn't reliably work well with Arial (as far as kerning).